# PHP OPCache: Cache by script checksum

Tags: php, opcache

Is there a feature of OP Cache to cache based on checksum/md5/crc of the php script?
Say you install 100 separate instances of WordPress (or similar) running on the same PHP FPM instance.

Even if 99% of the scripts in all installs of wordpress are the same, each path of the script takes space from OP Cache (max accelerated files counter and memory space). We can see the usages numbers in OP Cache increases equally to number of files.

Can one somehow configure it to detect that the file (and therefore the resulting opcode) will be the same?